# Android app identifier?

Tags: applications, malware, bloatware

Is there such a thing as a searchable database or a website anywhere online where someone can type in the name of an app or a package name and see a summary of what the app is for, if it is a system app, if it is just Android or iOS, list of permissions needed, etc?

I guess sort of an app dictionary/encyclopedia with more in depth info than what searching Google Play will give me.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you want that Google Play isn't giving you?

Comment: @DanHulme Reading between the lines: whether it's a system app, and the *full* list of permissions? Whether it's an iOS app *might* be indicated by not finding it there. And unfortunately, there are tons of apps whe one has to guess really hard "what the app is for" :)

Answer (score 1):

Unlikely such a site exists *and is complete*. See the two links in [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/140119/16575): [The first](http://www.freewarelovers.com/android/apps) currently covers 1718 apps, [the second](http://www.appsapk.com/android/all-apps/) ~7,350 apps. [My own site](https://android.izzysoft.de/) currently covers ~13,000+ apps (from multiple sources: GPlay, F-Droid, Aptoide "Apps", Xposed Repo).

Google Play covers >1 Mio apps, and I have a lot of apps not covered there (so do F-Droid (~1,800 apps) and Aptoide (~90,000 apps in their main repo, plus tons more in other "user-repos"). Then there are those apps offered outside of stores at all, e.g. only on the website of some company.

All that's left is typing the package name (surrounded by quotes) into a search box (Google, DuckDuckGo, whatever) and see what pops up. As you're specifically after malware: those results sometimes include links to scan details by several known anti-X companies, which are interesting (but not easy to read).

Comment: We could theoretically build an A.I. to mine from a search engine's results, and then have the relevant info of a package included in a database, couldn't we?

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman oh, [*theoretically* we could be millionaires](http://www.slightlywarped.com/jokes/jokes/difference_between_theory_and_fact.htm) :)

Comment: Nice example, pal. Still, it's when hypothesis gets applied, that we have changes. And what you did, was to give me a nice idea.

Comment: Looking forward to what that might become, @DeathMaskSalesman – don't forget to update us then!

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure if any such searchable database or a website is even possible for anyone to create (including Google itself), given the current size of Android apps, the indie app development ecosystem of Android  and plethora of Android devices on offer, which varies from country to country and more.

I guess the simplest approach is to take it case-by-case for each app.

**If you find a new/unknown app, just do a quick Google Search using app's Name.**

Most likely that you will find a link to Either Google Play store (if that app is hosted on Google Play) or some other Link from where you can download the APK for the app. Developers tend to provide enough information (such as app permissions) about the app so that user can see and install apps through these links.

Having said that, I found few useful links/sites which can be visited for app info.

[Link-1](http://www.freewarelovers.com/android/apps), [Link-2](http://www.appsapk.com/android/all-apps/)

Of course, these links/sites have their limitations and they do not have EVERY Single app which is ever developed for Android.